# Node.js Sequelize returns date minus 1 day

Tags: node.js, sql-server, sequelize.js

Sequelize is returning the date -1 day.  For instance if I do a select statement with a date in WHERE for:
     `"date":"2017-01-01"` 
it will return: 
     `'2016-12-31'`.

Everything else will be correct.  SQL Select statement that should match Sequelizes statement also displays correct information.  The timezones match..

```
router.post("/perUser", async (req, res) => { 

Labor.findAll({
    where: {
      clock: req.body.clock,
      date: req.body.date,
      entered_by: req.body.entered_by
    }
  })
    .then(labor => {
      console.log(labor);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
});
```

Data sent:

```
{
    "clock":"000072",
    "date":"2017-01-01",
    "entered_by":"username removed"
}
```

Response:

```
{
      id: 1272,
      clock: '000072',
      name: 'removed',
      rate: 13,
      swo: 'removed',
      cust_no: 'removed',
      customer: 'removed',
      wcn: 'removed',
      hours: '1',
      labor_dollars: 13,
      burden: 23.4,
      entered_by: 'removed',
      team_no: '14',
      date: '2016-12-31',
      decHours: null
    }
```

So I'm guessing there is a setting or something I'm missing in either sequelize or node, but google turns up nothing... any real help will be appreciated.

Comment: maybe a timezone error. check [this](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4858#issuecomment-235402396)

Comment: "The timezones match.."

Comment: @John I did try this date: {
      type: Sequelize.DATEONLY,
      get: function() {
        return moment.utc(this.getDataValue("date")).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
      }                                                                                                                           no luck though. Thanks for the attempt.

Answer (score 3):

you can define getter for date column in the model definition:

```
date: { 
type: DataTypes.DATE,
allowNull: true,
get() {
const date = this.getDataValue('date') ? moment(this.getDataValue('date')).format('YYYY-MM-DD') : null;
return date;
 } 
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Works perfect